# How to open or save as ico in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, cs6, save

[This plugin to open and save as .ico](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/icoformat/trunk/dist/README.html) in Photoshop has been around for a while, but I can't seem to make it work for CS6. According to [this question in the Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4453679), the plug-in works if installed in `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Required\Plug-Ins\File Formats` but it's not doing anything. Do you know of any alternative plugins for CS6? I'm using win seven 64 bits.

EDIT: The plugin does work, just not for images that are bigger than `256px x 256px`.

Comment: I always use this website when I need to convert my files to ICO files: http://www.convertico.com/

Comment: Thanks @Johannes. But I found two downsides to that site (and the others I tried): It doesn't go bigger than 256px, and when converting below 128px it creates a pack with automatic resized icons.

Comment: Ah, I only use it for customizing my own desktop and what not. I wasn't aware of those limitations, thank you.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but more of an alternative: I have been using GIF Movie gear http://www.gamani.com/ to create *.ico files for quite some time now. It's not free, however.

Comment: Does the .ico format support images bigger than 256×256? I've never seen an .ico tool that allows for bigger images (things may have changed since I last looked though).

Comment: @MarcEdwards They are being included now, because 512x512 is one of the requirements for Application icons in Mac OS X. Most of them don't yet, though, and I think the 512 one can also be jpg.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The full path is `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Required\Plug-Ins\File Formats`. Unless it's in `File Formats`, it won't show up in the export options.

Comment: Figured out why it "wasn't working". When trying to save a 512x512 icon, the option to save as ICO doesn't appear in the list. So there's finally something "you can only do you GIMP": save 512x512 icons! :D

Comment: Its not there, how do I add it?

Comment: I recommend the following: http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/ICOFormat

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this applies in CS6, but the method that I've been using in CS4 & 5 is just to create my `16px x 16px` Favicon, then `Save for Web`.

I save as either a `.png` or `.jpg` depending on the background, but when it asks for filename, I just add the `.ico`, like `favicon.ico`. Favicons work just fine.

I only use this for creating Favicons so I'm not sure if it would work the same for creating actual icons.

Comment: Have you tried it? I tried to make an ico-file to use in an application in Visual Studio, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: it also works if you create a png with 32x32.

Comment: This would only work when you're using the file in places where PNGs are accepted as well. The file extension doesn't change the file itself - it just tells the program that it is probably an ICO, not a PNG. Since the file you're saving is actually a PNG - that is, it is encoded as a PNG, you would need an application that understands how to decode that information to be able to use it, no matter what extension you use.

For web, generally PNGs are accepted as well, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Unless in fav**icons**... @PayodPanda

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use the 32-bit version of Photoshop CS6. I don't know if this is always the case, but I have Creative Cloud and installing Photoshop installed both 32-bit and 64-bit versions automatically. Just look through your start menu for the "Adobe Photoshop CS6" program (not "Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)"). You will need to install the plugin in the following folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Required\Plug-Ins\File Formats` (note the x86!)

Answer (score 4):

The solution to the issue for CS6 is the properties assigned to the folder "File Formats", go to that folder (C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Required\Plug-Ins\File Formats), right click, select properties, and turn off "Read Only", not checked, not blue, blank. Then apply or save changed, then extract the file to the folder. It should now work fine.

The reason it does this is because you exported the file to that folder, it appeared to copy to the folder, you closed the folder and opened Photoshop and it didn't work.  If you were to go back to the folder you'd see the file is not there because of the read only settings on the folder.

This worked for me, and should work for you. I hope. =)

Answer (score 4):

The problem on 64 bit is that the plugin does not work with images higher than 256px. Reduce the size of the image and you'll see that the options are shown to save as `.icp` or `.cur`.

---

Señores el problema en 64bit se debe a que el pluggin no permite trabajar con imágenes superiores a 256px, reduzcan el tamaño de la imagen y verán que aparecerán las opciones para guardar el `.ico` o `.cur`.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to "file format RGB" make sure the source file is 8 bit per color! In "save as - format" .ico doesn't appear, if your file is 16 bit per color.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't open the ico file but save it with just photoshop without requiring any plugin. The method is like this:

1. First Make sure `Image > Mode > RGB Color`  is selected.
2. Now save it `File > Save as`
3. And Make sure of the format `PNG(*.png)` is selected.
4. And just type `yourfilename.ico`
5. And save. Done.

Answer (score 1):

First check, if it's installed properly by looking for *"ICO (Windows Icon)"* under Photoshop's *"About Plug-in"* menu (on Windows, look under *"Help"*).

If you can see it, then it's installed. You may not see it listed in "save as", if you are trying to save `.psd` as `.ico`. Open a `.png` picture and click *"save as"*, hopefully you will see ICO in the Format drop-down list. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The correct location for the 64 bit version is:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Required\Plug-Ins\File Formats
```

The CS4/5 64 bit plugin works [from here](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/)
Just make sure you are using correct size and image mode (RGB)

Comment: This seems to just repeat some of the info in the question, rather than answering it.

Comment: Yes—the correct size and image mode. It seems (large) image dimensions are a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Like most people above I thought it wasn't working either, but it turned out my image size was too big, you have to resize to `32px x 32px` or less before you can save as an `.ico` format.. I personally put the plugin here :-  `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 (64 Bit)\Plug-ins\File Formats`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried like 5 of the answers here.

I ended up exporting from Photoshop to PNG then using GIMP to save as ICO. No plugins, no security settings, no x64 vs x86 stuff, no hassles. JUST SAVE AS! >:O

Answer (score -1):

You just follow this path to place your `ICOFormat64` plugin:

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Required\Plug-Ins\File Formats

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!  In the question, Yisela mentions installing it in that location.  Do you have any further information to add?