# Open an .ico file in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon

I have some icons I'd like to purchase and use from iconfinder.com, but they are only available as .ico files. I want to use these as part of a user-interface on a website, so I need them as either bitmap or vector format that I can bring into Photoshop to produce transparent .png files.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get .ico files into Photoshop through some third-party application? If it matters, I am using a Windows computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [**How to save as ico in Photoshop CS6**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9422/8708)

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks. I overlooked threads about saving .ico files since I was trying to do the opposite. That plugin works great.

Comment: Great! I edited the title of that question so that other people can find it easier, and I'll close this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various online and desktop `.ico` converting softwares, one online tool perfect for this is [iConvert](http://iconverticons.com/online/). It converts to various formats and lets you choose which one you want to download.

Comment: oo, that looks like that would work well too. There was a comment that seems to have vanished that suggested ICOformat plugin for photoshop which I'm using now and is working how i'd like it, but i will bookmark this site.

Comment: GIMP https://www.gimp.org/downloads/